# geom_rect equivalent of vjust and hjust

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to overlay outlined rectangles on a geom_tile ggplot. Right now I am calling the rectangles using geom_rect

`geom_rect(xmin=2, xmax=49, ymin=1, ymax=30, color="black",alpha=0.5, fill=NA, size = 0.3) +
  geom_rect(xmin=7, xmax=45, ymin=5, ymax=42, color="black",alpha=0.5, fill=NA, size = 0.3)`

The problem is that the line for the edge of the rectangle falls directly in the center of the tile. Essentially, the position of the edge it is acting like

`geom_raster(vjust = 0.5, hjust=0.5)`

Unfortunately, geom_rect doesn't have `hjust` or `vjust` parameters. How can I change the position of the rectangle so that the edge of the rectangle falls between cells (as if I was setting `hjust = 0` or `hjust = 1` and the same for `vjust`)?

Comment: It's hard to understand what kind of plot you want to generate. Please provide all code (with `geom_tile`)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you.